# Storing nested data in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following model of data:

### Topic

Title

Body

Children - Contains more topics

I'm trying to figure out the best way to store this information. Should I flatten all the documents and store them individually or should I store documents such that the children of topics and their children and so on are all nested within a single document? The latter approach makes me think that it may not be flexible.

Any advice would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to do:

For fast full text search, it's better to use inverted index:

> An inverted index consists of a list of all the unique words that appear in any document, and for each word, a list of the documents in which it appears.
>   https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/inverted-index.html

Otherwise: use forward index with nested objects (faster indexing, slower queries). Or else parent-child relationships (more efficient indexing)

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html